# webpack umd lib and external files

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I want to package my react component as a `umd` lib.

below is webpack my setting:

```js
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: [
    './lib/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'lib.js',
    library: 'lib',
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loaders: ['babel'],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  },
  externals: {
    "react": "React"
  }
}
```

And then after I require the package in my other component in this way

`example.js`

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {lib} from "../dist/lib";
```

And above component's webpack setting is :

```js
module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: [
    './examples/example'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loaders: ['babel'],
        exclude: /node_modules/
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

After I compile the `example.js` file, it shows the error:

```
Line 3: Did you mean "react"?
  1 | (function webpackUniversalModuleDefinition(root, factory) {
  2 |   if(typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module === 'object')
> 3 |       module.exports = factory(require("React"));
    |                                    ^
  4 |   else if(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)
  5 |       define(["React"], factory);
  6 |   else if(typeof exports === 'object')
```

I think the error is from the externals setting, cause after I remove `externals: {react: "React"}`, it works.

I search some related answers but can't fix it.

Does anyone have any idea of this? thanks.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I found the answer!

The reason is `umd` need to set the different external value (reference [doc](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#externals)).

Because I set the external react as `{react: React}`, webpack would try to find a package named `React`.

So you need to set the different value in different module definition.

```
externals: {
  "react": {
    root: 'React',
    commonjs2: 'react',
    commonjs: 'react',
    amd: 'react'
  }
}
```

Then it fix!

Comment: Thanks for posting this! Saved me a lot of headache today

Comment: Which version of webpack are you using ? does it still work with webpack 2 ?

Comment: @BigDong I have not tried webpack 2 yet. Does it not work on webpack 2?

Comment: Thanks for posting this. I tried this with webpack 4 and it works

Comment: thanks a lot! thank you man! i'm searching for 3 days and as the webpack docs are just boolshits i didn't see any help!