# Webpack UMD issue with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, umd

My library is built with webpack. The libraryTarget is UMD. The problem is with my dependencies. For example I am using jQuery. My webpack config looks like:

```
// Only relevant config is shown below
module.exports = {
    externals: {
        "jquery" : "jquery"
    }
};
```

In an AMD environment it works. I can require without problems:

```
define(['jquery'], function($) {});
```

But if I want to use the built file in a non module loader environment than I get "$ is not defined". Of course the solution is to change the webpack config this way:

```
// the Q is now upper case
"jquery" : "jQuery"
```

Than it works in a non module loader env. But this time its not working in the AMD env anymore because requirejs tries to load **jQuery.js** instead of **jquery.js**!

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: why don't you use same at both ends?

Comment: No, this isnt the solution.There is a resolve config property but I dont know if this is the solution.

Answer (score -1):

Solved issue this way (click to url) but I am not sure if its the correct way:

[webpack umd lib and external files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34252424/webpack-umd-lib-and-external-files)