# Webpack externals configuration - root key

Tags: javascript, webpack, webpack-externals

What does it mean and what is `root` for in Webpack [externals](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#externals) configuration?

```
module.exports = {
    output: {
        libraryTarget: "umd"
    },
    externals: [
        "add",
        {
            "subtract": {
                root: "subtract",
                commonjs2: "./subtract",
                commonjs: ["./math", "subtract"],
                amd: "subtract"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the answer here:

[webpack umd lib and external files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34252424/webpack-umd-lib-and-external-files)

Basically it applies to UMD modules and it is used to solve global dependencies when your module is loaded using the `<script>` tag or well a CDN repo.