# Configuring library as external in webpack does not work with UMD as libraryTarget

Tags: javascript, webpack, umd

I tried this the last two days and I can't get it to work like expected:
I want to build my own JavaScript library and register it under an already existing namespace ("OCA" - in this particular case). And as you might understand, I don't want to be forced to go without modern approaches like type safety through typescript or modules.

Therefore I use **webpack 2** and the `libraryTarget: umd` to register the output under "OCA.Ocr" (my library is named "Ocr"). This works like intended, but when it comes to the point that I want to use for example **underscorejs**, as it will be available globally in the application the library should be also delivered to, I cannot get it to work.
I followed the webpack configuration documentation and it says that the **externals** configuration option should be the way to go:

```
externals: { // object
    angular: "this angular", // this["angular"]
    react: { // UMD
      commonjs: "react",
      commonjs2: "react",
      amd: "react",
      root: "React"
    }
  }
  // Don't follow/bundle these modules, but request them at runtime from the environment
```

I used it like proposed by the guide but it doesn't work:

```
/* global __dirname, require, module*/

const webpack = require("webpack");
const UglifyJsPlugin = webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin;
const path = require("path");

module.exports = function (env) {
  let target = env.target;

  let libraryName = ["OCA", "Ocr"];

  let plugins = [];
  let outputFile;

  if (target === "production") {
    plugins.push(new UglifyJsPlugin({ minimize: true }));
  }
  outputFile = "ocr[name].min.js";

  const config = {
    entry: {
      app: __dirname + "/src/app.ts",
      personal: __dirname + "/src/personal.ts"
    },
    output: {
      path: __dirname + "/dist",
      filename: outputFile,
      library: libraryName,
      libraryTarget: "umd",
      umdNamedDefine: true
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.ts$/,
          enforce: "pre",
          loader: "tslint-loader",
          options: {
            tsConfigFile: "tsconfig.app.json",
          }
        },
        {
          test: /\.ts?$/,
          loader: "ts-loader",
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          options: {
            configFileName: "tsconfig.app.json"
          }
        }
      ],
    },
    resolve: {
      modules: [path.resolve("./src")],
      extensions: [".ts"],
    },
    externals: {
      underscore: { // UMD
        commonjs: "underscore",
        commonjs2: "underscore",
        amd: "underscore",
        root: "_"
      }
    },
    plugins: plugins,
  };

  return config;

}
```

My `app.ts` file which uses the underscore library (for example the `_.defer` method, which of course is not always the best to use) looks like that:

```
import _ from 'underscore';

export class App {

    constructor() {
        _.defer(() => {
            console.log('test');
        });
    }
}

export let $app: App = new App();
```

I included it in the application and also checked that the underscorejs library is getting loaded before my lib gets loaded by the browser, but the console output still states:

> TypeError: underscore_1.default is undefined

The compiled output is the following (maybe this helps a little bit):

```
(function webpackUniversalModuleDefinition(root, factory) {
    if(typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module === 'object')
        module.exports = factory(require("underscore"));
    else if(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)
        define("Ocr", ["underscore"], factory);
    else if(typeof exports === 'object')
        exports["Ocr"] = factory(require("underscore"));
    else
    root["OCA"] = root["OCA"] || {}, root["OCA"]["Ocr"] =     factory(root["_"]);
})(this, function(__WEBPACK_EXTERNAL_MODULE_1__) {
return /******/ (function(modules) { // webpackBootstrap
/******/    // The module cache
/******/    var installedModules = {};
/******/
/******/    // The require function
/******/    function __webpack_require__(moduleId) {
/******/
/******/        // Check if module is in cache
/******/        if(installedModules[moduleId]) {
/******/            return installedModules[moduleId].exports;
/******/        }
/******/        // Create a new module (and put it into the cache)
/******/        var module = installedModules[moduleId] = {
/******/            i: moduleId,
/******/            l: false,
/******/            exports: {}
/******/        };
/******/
/******/        // Execute the module function
/******/        modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module,     module.exports, __webpack_require__);
/******/
/******/        // Flag the module as loaded
/******/        module.l = true;
/******/
/******/        // Return the exports of the module
/******/        return module.exports;
/******/    }
/******/
/******/
/******/    // expose the modules object (__webpack_modules__)
/******/    __webpack_require__.m = modules;
/******/
/******/    // expose the module cache
/******/    __webpack_require__.c = installedModules;
/******/
/******/    // identity function for calling harmony imports with the correct     context
/******/    __webpack_require__.i = function(value) { return value; };
/******/
/******/    // define getter function for harmony exports
/******/    __webpack_require__.d = function(exports, name, getter) {
/******/        if(!__webpack_require__.o(exports, name)) {
/******/            Object.defineProperty(exports, name, {
/******/                configurable: false,
/******/                enumerable: true,
/******/                get: getter
/******/            });
/******/        }
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // getDefaultExport function for compatibility with non-harmony     modules
/******/    __webpack_require__.n = function(module) {
/******/        var getter = module && module.__esModule ?
/******/            function getDefault() { return module['default']; } :
/******/            function getModuleExports() { return module; };
/******/        __webpack_require__.d(getter, 'a', getter);
/******/        return getter;
/******/    };
/******/
/******/    // Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call
/******/    __webpack_require__.o = function(object, property) { return     Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(object, property); };
/******/
/******/    // __webpack_public_path__
/******/    __webpack_require__.p = "";
/******/
/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    return __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = 2);
    /******/ })
/************************************************************************/
/******/ ([
/* 0 */,
/* 1 */
/***/ (function(module, exports) {

module.exports = __WEBPACK_EXTERNAL_MODULE_1__;

/***/ }),
/* 2 */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";

Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var underscore_1 = __webpack_require__(1);
var App = (function () {
    function App() {
        underscore_1.default.defer(function () {
            console.log('test');
        });
    }
    return App;
}());
exports.App = App;
exports.$app = new App();


/***/ })
/******/ ]);
});
```

Does anyone know how this is working and what I will have to do? I am completely lost and now hoping for your help.

Btw: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34252424/webpack-umd-lib-and-external-files) is also not working for me.

Comment: I also asked this at [Github](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/4824) and it turned out, that this is a bug. I will give an update when it's fixed.

Comment: any update? I am also facing same issue with AMD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options here.  I recommend option #1.

In fact, if you use `UMD` and plan on supporting `node` (in addition to commonjs, amd, and browser), **always set `globalObject: 'this'`**

### Set `output.globalObject` to `this`, and use `externals.root`.

```
const config = {
    output: {
      library: libraryName,
      libraryTarget: "umd",
      globalObject: 'this' // <-- THIS IS THE IMPORTANT LINE FOR UMD+NODE
    },
    externals: {
      underscore: { // UMD
        commonjs: "underscore",
        commonjs2: "underscore",
        amd: "underscore",
        root: "_"
      }
    },
  };
```

**output.globalObject**

When targeting a library, especially when the libraryTarget is 'umd', this option indicates what global object will be used to mount the library. To make UMD build available on both browsers and Node.js, set output.globalObject option to 'this'.

### Use `externals.var` instead of `externals.root`.

```
    externals: {
      underscore: { // UMD
        commonjs: "underscore",
        commonjs2: "underscore",
        amd: "underscore",
        var: "_"
      }
    },
```

This is a *workaround* and does not require setting `globalObject: 'this'`

Answer (score 4):

I have the same issue as you, however, if you set the property var in the libraryTarget option, the variable stops being undefined. Maybe this will help you:

```
externals: {
    "lodash": { 
        var:'_'
    }
}
```

Comment: Saved my day, thank you! But why? there is nothing about this "var" property even in the official doc: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/

Comment: Hello @H0WARD, as you can see at the end of the Expose Library Section(https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/), there is a bug, but also a workaround.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me. Actually I tried with webpack 3.5.5 and v4 already. But it always says that "default" is undefined